# Synapse Analytics - How to find square bracket in text

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

Hi i want to find campaign that contain text with the square bracket as part of the text.

ESCAPE doesn't seem to work on Synapse Analytics

```
WHERE campaign LIKE '%[de]%' OR campaign LIKE '%[be]%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following queries in synapse to get text with square brackets

```sql
WHERE campaign LIKE '%[de]%'  OR campaign LIKE '%[be]%'
```

Or

**Using extra brackets**

```sql
WHERE campaign LIKE '%[[]de]%'  OR campaign LIKE '%[[]be]%'
```

***My sample data:***

[image]

***Output***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks extra brackets works!!

the thing about using

```
WHERE campaign LIKE '%[de]%'  OR campaign LIKE '%[be]%'
```

is that it gives me output that i don't want with [d] and [e] as well